# Approach to data wrapping

Tags: php, mysql, word-wrap

I'm developing in PHP and MySQL.

The information about the currently logged in user is stored in many different tables. The information that I need on each page, I preload. However if something is needed from a rarely accessed table - then I do

```
$newdata = $db->Query('SELECT * FROM rare_table WHERE user_id='.$user->id);
```

I would like to simplify the above to a point where I don't have to specify that the query should be limited to this particular user. An ideal function call would be:

```
$newdata = $user->Query('SELECT * FROM rare_table');
```

Obviously I'd have to parse the SQL and add a WHERE clause. Or add to the already existing clause.

**Questions**: are there tools to do this? How can I develop this? Is this even a good idea?

---

**Edit**: Found an [SQL parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4916-PHP-Build-a-tree-to-represent-an-SQL-query.html) that may assist those interested in doing this.

Comment: additionally, you may want to limit single row result queries. SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=x LIMIT 1

Comment: @dqhendricks For queries where a `WHERE` clause exists on a primary or unique key adding a `LIMIT 1` will slow down the query because it will keep track of row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to add a function to user

```
public function getRow($tableName)
{
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user_id = " . $this->$id;
     //run query
```

The issue is getting $db, does it belong to user?  do you have a function to get it?

```
public function getRowFrom($tableName)
{
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE user_id = " . $this->$id;
     $db = getDb(); //however you need to do this.  $this->db, DBTools::getDB(), call constructor here, etc.
     return $db->Query($sql);
}
```

and call it as

```
$user->getRowFrom('rareTableNo4');
```

Comment: What about other SQL functionality such as `LIMIT`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` etc, that go after the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: good point. what is your db object? if it uses `mysqli` or `PDO` i think there are built-in ways with parameterization.  otherwise, if you are going to be doing specific involved queries whats the user of saving `"user_id = {$user->id}"` out of the clause?  would probably make more sense to write the frequently used queries into user functions ie - `getAttribute($attName)`, `getCreatedTime()`, and do

Answer (score 0):

I generally create a class called User and instantiate a singleton for each page (with the logged-in user.). Additional instances can be created for other users (e.g. $u2 = new User($name);) Then such things get embedded in User.

Comment: This isn't really my question. I have a class just like you describe. My question is about transforming SQL statements such that I do not need to specify that I'm querying for data belonging to this user